# Performance: Creating an ArrayList from HashMap.values()

Tags: java, performance, collections, arraylist, hashmap

Question is how much it costs to create an ArrayList from a HashMap.values() Collection? Or creating the values Collection alone?
Assuming Map.size() > 100k.
Objects could also be held in ArrayList (instead of HashMap) all the time which has implications in other parts (modifications of elements, easy by key).
The ArrayList is used to iterate over every n-th element. (That's why the values collection can't be used directly). No modifications are done during the iteration.

Comment: The question is not clear.i didn't understand.

Comment: When you talk about "cost", do you mean, time or memory?

Answer (score 42):

`HashMap.values()` doesn't return an `ArrayList` of values but a `Values` Collection.

Source:

```
 public Collection<V> values() {
        Collection<V> vs = values;
        return (vs != null ? vs : (values = new Values()));
    }
```

`Values` is an `AbstractCollection`. The reason for values is just to reference HashMap's iterator.

Your question:

> Question is how much it costs to
>   create an ArrayList from a
>   HashMap.values() Collection?

That's a linear complexity (as Bozho said) since

```
ArrayList<V> valuesList = new ArrayList<V>(hashMap.values());
```

the ArrayList, `valuesList` calls the collection `hashMap` `toArray()` method which essentially does a `for` loop from 0..N (size) element in the collection.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 9):

`HashMap` internally stores values in a Collection `values`. Take a look at the [source code](http://kickjava.com/src/java/util/AbstractMap.java.htm) of `AbstractMap`, the parent of `HashMap`.

So `HashMap.values()` directly returns a `Collection`. There is no computation or data copying done. It's as fast as it can be.

Just get the values and then do a for loop:

```
int n = 5;  // every 5th element
Object[] values = hashMap.values().toArray();
int size = values.length;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i += n){
   values[i];
   // do something
)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use an `Iterator` to skip elements - just call `next()` many times.

Creating a list of any collection has a linear complexity.

Comment: makes sense. So I use iterator and call it.next() in a for loop since many times is a parameter.

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate on @Bozho's solution you can just do.

```
int count = 0;
for(Value value: map.values())
   if(count++ % 5 == 0)
     // do something.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create Your own HashMap, that holds the Arraylist collection of values directly (i do not believe that HashMap does it for free, the data structure for it is different). But this requires some additional coding from Your side.