# Sorting edges of a graph (based on Adjacency List representation) in Java

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures, graph, minimum-spanning-tree

I have a graph which stores it's edges using a HashMap as follows :

```
HashMap<Integer,LinkedList<Node>> adj;
```

where Node is defined ;

```
class Node
{
   int number;
   int weight;
}
```

eg

- 0 : <1,55> -> <2,54>   //node 0 is connected to node 1 with edge weight 55 and node 2 with edge     weight 54
- 1 : <0,43> -> <2,44>  //node 1 is connected to node 0 with edge weight 43 and node 2 with
  edge weight 44

I need to get a list of edges in sorted order by weight and I have no clue how to go about it. I am trying to implement Kruskal's MST.

Is it possible to sort the graph I have defined? If not please suggest a better way of storing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start by creating an `Edge` class:

```
class Edge implements Comparable<Edge> { // Important: must implement Comparable. More on this later
    public Node first; // first connected node
    public Node second; // second connected node
    public int weight; // move edge weight to Edge class

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Edge e) {
        if (weight < e.weight) {
            return -1;
        } else if (weight > e.weight) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Because the `weight` variable is in the `Edge` class, it isn't needed in `Node`, so you can remove it:

```
class Node {
    public int number;
    // add more variables later is you need here
}
```

Now, for your program (if there isn't a requirement against it), I would define your list like this:

```
HashMap<Node, List<Edge>> adj; // use any list implementation you want
```

This will represent the graph like this inside your program (copied from your example):

- Node 0: Edge(Node 0, Node 1, 55), Edge(Node 0, Node 2, 54)
- Node 1: Edge(Node 1, Node 0, 43), Edge(Node 1, Node 2, 44)

**To answer your question**, lets find the edges sorted by edge weight:

```
ArrayList<Edge> sortedEdges = new ArrayList<Edge>();
for (List<Edge> connectedEdges : adj.values()) {
    sortedEdges.addAll(connectedEdges);
}
Collections.sort(sortedEdges);
```

This simply takes all the `Edge`s in `adj` and puts them all in one list, and then sorts them according to their weight (because we made `Edge` extend [`Comparable<Edge>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)). As per the [Javadoc on `Collections.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29), the `sort()` method uses merge sort, which runs in `O(nlog(n))` time:

> Implementation note: This implementation is a stable, adaptive, iterative mergesort that requires far fewer than n lg(n) comparisons when the input array is partially sorted, while offering the performance of a traditional mergesort when the input array is randomly ordered.

Getting the list of all `Edge`s by `adj.values` takes `O(n)` time (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4255296/837703)), so the total time complexity of getting the list of edges sorted by weight will be `O(n) + O(nlog(n))` = **`O(nlog(n))`**.

So there you go. I hope this helped :)

Comment: Side note: you may be able to get rid of that one `O(n)` in there by implementing your own merge sort that will sort the list as you iterate over it. I'm not sure how much time you'll save by doing this though...

Answer (score 0):

If you have the freedom to change the way nodes are represented, I would like to suggest changing it. Currently the `Node` class really represents an edge (and a node is represented by `Integer`, i.e., keys to the `adj` variable.

For example, the following seems more natural:

```
Set<Node> nodes = new HashSet<>(); // The enclosing class keeps track of all nodes.

// Represents each node.
class Node {
    int nodeId = /* ... */;

    // The Node class keeps track of its neighbors, sorted by their weights.
    SortedMap<Integer,Node> edges = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
}
```

Then, whenever you need to do things in the descending order of the weight, you could do something like:

```
void method(Node node) {
    Iterator<Integer> iter = node.edges.keySet().iterator(); // Iterates in descending order.
    while(iter.hasNext()) {
        int weight = iter.next();
        Node neighbor = node.edges.get(weight);

        doSomething( /* ... */ );
    }
}
```

Comment: This method only sorts the edges of one node. The OP wanted to get a list of all the edges in the entire graph, sorted by weight.